# Using SharePoint with several Active Directories

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, active-directory, ldap

How can I configure SharePoint 2010 to use several different Active Directories for authentication?

Thanks!

Comment: I think this belongs on serverfault.com

Answer (score 3):

In central administration you go to "Application Management" then "Manage service applications" , "User Profile Service Application" , "Configure Synchronization Connections" and there you can create a new connection. After that you can start a sync and it should pull in the accounts from both or more connections.

Comment: Thanx! Can i do the same thing with SharePoint 2010 Foundation?

Comment: So it pulls the user info in?  And then does Auth on the fly?

Comment: It pulls in the users and what groups they are in and such and you can provide SharePoint permissions to those groups and filters to global groups that you can add the AD groups to in Central Admin. As to if this works with SharePoint 2010 I do not know because I have only ever worked with SharePoint server.

Answer (score 3):

To authenticate users in many ADs, you have to implement ADFS services in each domain and configure your SharePoint Application with the Federation Authentication mode.
User Profile Service only sync users' profile information for you but can't authenticate users.
You can check it [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB8QFjAA&url=http://blogs.technet.com/b/speschka/archive/2010/07/30/configuring-sharepoint-2010-and-adfs-v2-end-to-end.aspx&ei=gbz6TYeqD4_PrQeIqoDADw&usg=AFQjCNHaVg1eUNT7j-tlJ024IYeQGuIAyw).